# Looking for an image to vector convert capability without installing on computer?

Tags: gratis, vector-graphics, image-conversion

I am looking for a software that does convert from image to vector, but the one that does not install on my computer. I am familiar that there are a few that are out there are online.

1. It has to be free
2. No install
3. Convert to any kind of format to save.

Comment: Online only or able to run locally from USB drive, _without installation_?  If the latter is acceptable which OS?

Comment: Yeah, I could use that to run from USB. I forgot what it was called. I had one from a different software that ran from USB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App to convert existing image files to vector graphics?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/764/app-to-convert-existing-image-files-to-vector-graphics)

Comment: Why are the ones you are familiar with online not work for you? What formats specifically do you need this to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape can be found on the internet in portable format, and it allows you to convert any image to a vector image. You can do this by going **Path > Trace Bitmap** in the menu. But I have to admit it's not the most straightforward solution, because you have to do a series of steps to achieve the conversion.
In overall:
1) yes, Inkscape is free
2) If you download the portable version, no install is required
3) It does the job, however it's not like a solution where you "drag and drop" and the job is done.
4) It supports most of the general formats. (png, jpg, bmp, but im not sure about tiff)

There are portable packages for windows, but for linux I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I would have to agree with you about Inkscape. I used to have Photoshop software myself but it is way old now... I have use that  tool you told me and tried that and it not the most straightforward so it takes some time to do some steps... That one I had I installed on my "home" computer and cannot use it at work which is why I can't use it at work.

Comment: I'm not sure if svg is the right format for your vector images but there is an alternative, which is not really a desktop app, rather a free online service: https://convertio.co/jpg-svg/
But this one only converts jpg to svg, and it can't deal with complex images. If you try to convert a complex one, it gives you back an empty svg file.